# In org-mode, can I show the formula of the table cell at point in eldoc?

Tags: org-table, eldoc, formula

I'd like `C-c ?` to happen automatically when I focus on a table cell, is there something built-in to do this?

(Or is there some other way to quickly show which cells are "input" vs "output"?)

Comment: There are multiple questions bundled in to a single question ... and I have addressed each component of the question.  As the screenshots show, the snippets work reasonably well.  It is possible that are slow on large tables with too many formulae etc.  The snippets show good starting points and the mechanics involved to dig deeper

Comment: The final solution that consolidates all the approaches is here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80851/42623.  This solution has too many moving parts.  The other solutions are also solutions,    in the sense that they are fairly easy  to understand (=  less bugs).  IOW, _different solutions_ for _different needs_.  Leave the other answers intact ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like C-c ? to happen automatically when I focus on a table cell, is there something built-in to do this?

To get this

***Display Table Cell info as `eldoc` string***

[image: Table Cell info as eldoc string]

on this

```
#+NAME: table1
#+CAPTION: Table 1
| Student  | Mark1 | Mark2 | Mark3 | Result | Result-simple | ResultSkaled |
|----------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+--------------|
| Student1 |     2 |     3 |     4 |      9 |             9 |          900 |
| Student2 |     4 |     2 |     1 |      7 |             7 |          700 |
#+TBLFM: $5=vsum($2..$4)::$6=$2+$3+$4::$7=vsum($2..$4)*100
```

this seems like a good starting point

```lisp
(defun my-tblcell-info ()
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) 'format))
    (cond
     ((and (eq 'table-cell (org-element-type (org-element-context))))
      (unless org-table-overlay-coordinates
        (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays))
      (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
      (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
      (org-table-field-info nil)))))

(defun my-install-tblcell-info-as-eldoc-string ()
  (add-function :before-until (local 'eldoc-documentation-function)
                #'my-tblcell-info)
  (eldoc-add-command 'org-cycle 'org-shifttab)
  (turn-on-eldoc-mode))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-install-tblcell-info-as-eldoc-string)
```

If `org table` is a too big to analyze, you may have to build the docstring in a callback.

For quick results, the above snippet works reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like C-c ? to happen automatically when I focus on a table cell, i

To get this

***`mouse-1` or `left click` shows table cell info at point***

[image: mouse-1 shows info about cell at point]

do this

```lisp
(defun my-org-table-info (&optional event promote-to-region)
  (interactive "e\np")
  (mouse-set-point event promote-to-region)
  (pcase (org-element-type (org-element-context))
    (`table-cell
     (unless org-table-overlay-coordinates
       (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays))
     (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
     (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
     (call-interactively 'org-table-field-info))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-1>") 'my-org-table-info)
```

Answer (score 1):

> (Or is there some other way to quickly show which cells are "input" vs "output"?)

The snippet gives the contour of possible solution and is **NOT** *production ready*.  Right now, it doesn't overlays used for highlighting etc.

**TODO**: *Destructure the `message` emitted by stock `org-table-field-info` with `pcase` `rx` pattern may be.*

To get this

***Highight dependent cells of a table with `M-x my-org-table-highlight-dependent-cells`***

[image: Highight dependent cells of a table]

on this

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun my-org-table-field-info ()
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message)
               (lambda (fmt-string &rest args)
                 args)))
      (cond
       ((and (eq 'table-cell (org-element-type (org-element-context))))
        (unless org-table-overlay-coordinates
          (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays))
        (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
        (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
        (org-table-field-info nil)))))

  (defun my-org-table-field-is-a-formula-p (table-field-info)
    ;; Poor man's destructuring of message emitted by stock
    ;; `org-table-field-info'
    (when (org-string-nw-p (nth 7 table-field-info))
      (nth 7 table-field-info)))

  (defun my-org-table-highlight-dependent-cells ()
    (interactive)
    (when (org-at-table-p)
      (goto-char (org-table-end))
      (ignore-errors
        (while t
          (org-table-previous-field)
          (when (my-org-table-field-is-a-formula-p
                 (my-org-table-field-info))
            (pcase-let* ((`(,type ,(map :begin :end) ,contents) (org-element-context)))
              (thread-first (thread-last (list begin (1- end))
                                         (apply #'make-overlay))
                            (overlay-put 'face 'secondary-selection))))))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: my-org-table-highlight-dependent-cells

#+NAME: table1
#+CAPTION: Table 1
| Student  | Mark1 | Mark2 | Mark3 | Result | Result-simple | ResultSkaled |
|----------+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------------+--------------|
| Student1 |     2 |     3 |     4 |      9 |             9 |          900 |
| Student2 |     4 |     2 |     1 |      7 |             7 |          700 |
#+TBLFM: $5=vsum($2..$4)::$6=$2+$3+$4::$7=vsum($2..$4)*100
```

do this

```lisp
(defun my-org-table-field-info ()
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message)
             (lambda (fmt-string &rest args)
               args)))
    (cond
     ((and (eq 'table-cell (org-element-type (org-element-context))))
      (unless org-table-overlay-coordinates
        (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays))
      (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
      (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
      (org-table-field-info nil)))))

(defun my-org-table-field-is-a-formula-p (table-field-info)
  ;; Poor man's destructuring of message emitted by stock
  ;; `org-table-field-info'
  (when (org-string-nw-p (nth 7 table-field-info))
    (nth 7 table-field-info)))

(defun my-org-table-highlight-dependent-cells ()
  (interactive)
  (when (org-at-table-p)
    (goto-char (org-table-end))
    (ignore-errors
      (while t
        (org-table-previous-field)
        (when (my-org-table-field-is-a-formula-p
               (my-org-table-field-info))
          (pcase-let* ((`(,type ,(map :begin :end) ,contents) (org-element-context)))
            (thread-first (thread-last (list begin (1- end))
                                       (apply #'make-overlay))
                          (overlay-put 'face 'secondary-selection))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Destructure the message emitted by stock org-table-field-info with pcase rx pattern may be

Done.

#### What does the Elisp Recipe do?

#### Recipe

This recipe does the following

- `mouse-1` on a table cell highlight the table, it also prints table cell info as `eldoc` string
- When on a table, if use `<tab>`, `<backtab>` (translated from `S-<iso-lefttab>`), `C-f`, `C-b`, `C-n`, `C-p` to navigate around the table, it prints the table cell info as `eldoc` string.  (*In this case, no highlighting of dependent cell would happen.*)

#### Screenshots of recipe in action

##### Demo-1: What happens when `mouse-1` on a Table cell

*(Note that this table is a fairly complex, and names some fields, and columns)*

[image: mouse-1 on a Table Cell]

##### Demo-2: What happens when `mouse-1` on a different Table

[image: mouse-1 on another Table]

#### `Org` file used for Demo

```
#+NAME: revenue
#+CAPTION: Quarterly Revenue
#+ATTR_ODT: :style "Academic"
|       | Jan | Feb | Mar | Sum |
|-------+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| North | 5.1 | 1.7 | 5.6 |     |
| South | 7.6 | 3.7 | 0.4 |     |
| East  | 9.5 | 0.4 | 9.6 |     |
| West  | 4.8 | 5.7 | 5.9 |     |
|-------+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| Sum   |     |     |     |     |
#+TBLFM: $5=vsum($2..$4)::@6$2..@6$4=vsum(@I..@II)::@>$>=vsum(@I..@II)

#+NAME: table4
#+CAPTION: Table 4
|---+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+----------------|
|   | Student | Prob 1 | Prob 2 | Prob 3 | Total | Note | Copy of Prob 1 |
|---+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+----------------|
| ! |         |     P1 |     P2 |     P3 |   Tot |      |                |
| # | Maximum |     10 |     15 |     25 |    50 | 10.0 |             10 |
| ^ |         |     m1 |     m2 |     m3 |    mt |      |                |
|---+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+----------------|
| # | Peter   |     10 |      8 |     23 |    41 |  8.2 |             10 |
| # | Sam     |      2 |      4 |      3 |     9 |  1.8 |              2 |
|---+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+----------------|
|   | Average |        |        |        |  25.0 |      |                |
| ^ |         |        |        |        |    at |      |                |
| $ | max=50  |        |        |        |       |      |                |
|---+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------+----------------|
#+TBLFM: $6=vsum($P1..$P3)::$7=10*$Tot/$max;%.1f::$8=$3
```

#### Elisp Recipe

This recipe does the following

- `mouse-1` on a table cell highlight the table, it also prints table cell info as `eldoc` string
- When on a table, if use `<tab>`, `<backtab>` (translated from `S-<iso-lefttab>`), `C-f`, `C-b`, `C-n`, `C-p` to navigate around the table, it prints the table cell info as `eldoc` string.  (*In this case, no highlighting of dependent cell would happen.*)

```lisp
(defun my-tblcell-info ()
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) 'format))
    (when (and (org-at-table-p)
               (eq 'table-cell (org-element-type (org-element-context))))
      (unless org-table-overlay-coordinates
        (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays))
      (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
      (org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
      (substring-no-properties (org-table-field-info nil)))))

(defun my-tblcell-info-as-plist (field-info)
  (when (stringp field-info)
    (pcase-let* (;; (field-info
                 ;;  "line @3, col $6 or $Tot, ref @3$6 or F3 or $mt, formula: $6=vsum($P1..$P3)")
                 ((rx
                   "line " (let line (one-or-more any))
                   ", col " (let col (let col-1 (minimal-match (one-or-more any))) (opt " or " (let col-2 (one-or-more any))))
                   ", ref " (let ref (minimal-match (one-or-more any)))
                   " or " (and
                           (let rest-1 (minimal-match (one-or-more any)))
                           (opt " or " (let rest-2 (minimal-match (one-or-more any))))
                           (opt ", formula: " (let rest-3 (minimal-match (one-or-more any)))))
                   eos)
                  field-info))
      (list :line line
            :cols (list col-1 col-2)
            :refs (list ref rest-1 rest-2)
            :formula rest-3))))

(defun my-tblcell-info-as-string ()
  (when-let ((plist (my-tblcell-info-as-plist (my-tblcell-info))))
    (format "%S" plist)
    ;; (plist-get plist :formula)
    ))

(defun my-tblcell-is-a-formula-p (plist)
  (plist-get plist :formula))

(defun my-install-tblcell-info-as-eldoc-string ()
  (add-function :before-until (local 'eldoc-documentation-function)
                #'my-tblcell-info-as-string)
  (eldoc-add-command 'org-cycle 'org-shifttab 'my-tblcell-highlight-dependent-cells)
  (turn-on-eldoc-mode))

(defun my-tblcell-highlight-dependent-cells ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (when (org-at-table-p)
      (goto-char (org-table-end))
      (ignore-errors
        (while t
          (org-table-previous-field)
          (when (my-tblcell-is-a-formula-p
                 (my-tblcell-info-as-plist
                  (my-tblcell-info)))
            (pcase-let* ((`(,type ,(map :begin :end) ,contents) (org-element-context)))
              (thread-first (thread-last (list begin (1- end))
                                         (apply #'make-overlay))
                            (overlay-put 'face 'secondary-selection)))))))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-install-tblcell-info-as-eldoc-string)

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-1>") 'my-tblcell-highlight-dependent-cells)
```